# Why can't I install the Ruby gem rspec on Cloud9?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rubygems

I am trying to run

```
gem install rspec --version 3.2.0
```

from Cloud9. It gives me this error:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rspec' (= 3.2.0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) for "api.rubygems.org" port 443 (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

When I run the same command from a linux terminal it successfully installs the desired gem (six gems in total).

Why do I get the error on Cloud9?

I also have a file called Gemfile in my Workspace on Cloud9 with contents:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "rspec", "~> 3.2.0
```

Trying the following command on the Cloud9 command line:

```
bundle install
```

I get the following:

```
Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/
Retrying source fetch due to error (2/3): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.org/
Retrying source fetch due to error (3/3): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.org/
Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.org/
```

Another thing: if I go to the Rubygems website and search for the gem I want, the link is https://rubygems.org/gems/rspec/versions/3.2.0
Under versions, if I click on the version I want, shouldn't it download? I don't get a download.

Comment: What happens if you don't set a version for rspec? Is this happening for any other gem?

Comment: gem install also has two flags that might give you some more interesting output: --debug -V

Comment: I just ran bundle install again (some 10 hours after I had an issue), and it now works. Does this mean it was likely a problem with the RubyGems website?

Comment: RubyGems did not have server problems according to the [uptime page](https://uptime.rubygems.org). I installed RSpec on many of my workspaces. I am not sure if that was a network hiccup but I highly doubt it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to run `gem install rspec` and you will get the 3.3.2 version.

[image]